How to add custom Class to attachment in WordPress media Library page
I want to add a custom class to WordPress media library Grid view items. But Its not added by extending wp.media.view.Attachment.
I am working with a plugin which will create a blur data for uploaded images. I'm trying to add a class name to that image if the blur data already genarated. After googling I found that it can be done by JS only for Grid View. For list view I've added a data column. That's working fine.
But stuck on Grid view(Not in Modal). If it's done by php then it'll not take much CPU, I've tried checking the metadata with ajax and it's consuming CPU and that will execute every time visiting the upload page. My first priority is to add the class using php, but as far as I found, it's only can be done using js by extending wp.media.view. So, I'm trying that approach. but it's not working.
    let view = wp.media.view.Attachment;
    // Extend the Attachment prototype to add custom className
    view = view.extend({
      // Add custom class to the Attachment
      className: function () {
        return "has-blur";
      }
    });

    return view;


In simple words, I want to add a class in the marked element/item. Is there any PHP way to add a class to the attachment li, or if I'm missing something with the JS? Any kind of help or suggestions appreciated.
I don't have much knowledge on WP core

After some research, I found that modifying the grid view is best done using JavaScript by extending wp.media.view.Attachment

Enqueue your custom script
Extend the Attachment view

Here’s a code snippet
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  // Ensure the wp.media is ready
  wp.media.view.AttachmentGridItem = wp.media.view.Attachment.extend({
    initialize: function () {
      // Call the original initialize method
      wp.media.view.Attachment.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

      // Check if the attachment has blur data
      if (this.model.get('meta') && this.model.get('meta').has_blur_data) {
        this.$el.addClass('has-blur');
      }
    }
  });

  // Override the view when the media library is loaded
  wp.media.view.Attachment = wp.media.view.AttachmentGridItem;
});

